# How can I lock Row 1 of all the sheets in a workbook and remaining cells unrestricted

Tags: excel-formula, range, office365

I want to lock Row 1 of each worksheet in a workbook for editing however at the same time I want the remaining area to be free and unrestricted for any edits.
I have Office 365.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple sheets at once by left clicking on the tab while holding the control key.

1. Select multiple sheets at once by left clicking on the tab while holding the control key.
2. Left click the button to the left of the column header 'A' and above row header '1', to select all the cells.
   [image: Example]
3. Right click and select "Format Cells.."
4. Select the Protection tab and clear the locked button.
5. Select row 1 by clicking on the '1' row header.
6. Right click and select "Format Cells.." and set the locked button.
7. Select each tab, one at a time, and go to the Review tab and select "Protect Sheet"